# Flutter - "requires SDK version >=2.18.0-271.2.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed." Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am getting an error like this:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.5.

Because exampleapp requires SDK version >=2.18.0-271.2.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because keycehennemi requires SDK version >=2.18.0-271.2.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0-271.2.beta <3.0.0'
```

Exactly nek of the `sdk`? I do not understand. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Run `flutter --version` to check your installed flutter and dart version

My case I am using stable version

```dart
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git  
Framework • revision f1875d570e (5 weeks ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

You can use

```dart
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
```

You can track the version from [/sdk/releases](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Answer (score 4):

You should try this.

`flutter channel master
flutter upgrade`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, I had an old version of Dart from last year, v2, created a new Flutter project that require >3 <4 and running those commands solved my issue. Thanks