# The app was working fine and after the latest update to flutter it is giving this error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, null, null-safety

I hope to solve this error because most of the applications that I work on are giving the same or similar error

I tried downgrading the sdk to a lower level but it gives the same error

" The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0-146.2.beta.  Because movies_booking requires SDK version >=3.0.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed "

The app was working fine and after the latest update to flutter it is giving this error

Comment: You need to check what version you have of Flutter and Dart and use the right one in the code. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73426677/13058371) ... Also, always make sure to use packages where their creator keeps the package up-to-date, that would be better, I am saying this just cause I didn't find it on `pub.dev`

Comment: run these command. . * flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get

Comment: Upgrade your flutter package to latest one .

Comment: If not resolve the issues , update your Flutter and dart SDK version to latest . As well as packages also .